# Using a C++ TCP client socket on a specific network interface Linux/Unix

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have the following code which by default connects to interface "eth0" which is a 1G NIC, but I would like to connect using "eth5", which is a 10G NIC.

```
 class TCPClientSocket {
  protected:
    int socket_file_descriptor_;

  public:

    TCPClientSocket ( ) 
      : socket_file_descriptor_ ( -1 )
    {
      /* socket creation */
      socket_file_descriptor_ = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
      if ( socket_file_descriptor_ < 0 ) { exit(1); }
    }

    void Connect ( const std::string & _ors_ip_, const int _ors_port_ ) {
      struct sockaddr_in ors_Addr_ ;
      bzero ( &ors_Addr_, sizeof ( ors_Addr_ ) ) ;
      ors_Addr_.sin_family = AF_INET;
      ors_Addr_.sin_port = htons ( _ors_port_ );
      inet_pton ( AF_INET, _ors_ip_.c_str(), &(ors_Addr_.sin_addr) );

      if ( connect ( socket_file_descriptor_, (struct sockaddr *) &ors_Addr_, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "connect() failed on %s:%d\n", _ors_ip_.c_str( ), _ors_port_ );
        close ( socket_file_descriptor_ );
        socket_file_descriptor_ = -1;
      }
    }

    inline int WriteN ( const unsigned int _len_, const void * _src_ ) const {
      if ( socket_file_descriptor_ != -1 ) {
        return write ( socket_file_descriptor_, _src_, _len_ );
      }
      return -1;
    }

    inline int ReadN ( const unsigned int _len_, void * _dest_ ) const {
      if ( socket_file_descriptor_ != -1 ) {
        return read ( socket_file_descriptor_, _dest_, _len_ );
      }
      return -1;
    }

    inline bool IsOpen ( ) const { return ( socket_file_descriptor_ != -1 ) ; }
    inline int socket_file_descriptor() const { return socket_file_descriptor_; }    
    void Close ( ) {
      if ( socket_file_descriptor_ != -1 ) {
        shutdown ( socket_file_descriptor_, SHUT_RDWR );
        close ( socket_file_descriptor_ );
        socket_file_descriptor_ = -1;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically bind a socket to only one network interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119401/how-do-i-dynamically-bind-a-socket-to-only-one-network-interface)

Comment: Could you add more details to the scenario ? @SB I am not (yet) sure it's a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @cnicular The way we use this class is just instantiate it and call connect. I was hoping to just change the class so that it automatically uses the "eth5" NIC. As a next change we would then add an argument to the instantiation which allowed the user to control which NIC to use.

Comment: Out of interest why not solve it out side of the application with a metric on the interfaces?

Comment: @awoodland I did not understand the "metric on the interfaces" ?

Comment: look at the output of `ifconfig` and `ip route` (on Linux, similar on other systems) to see current metrics. Probably '1' on all your interfaces. You can make the system prefer different network interfaces and routes, but fall back if one goes down by setting the metric. So you can say "prefer faster link" or "prefer cheaper route" etc. without the applications having to care about details like interface names.

Comment: @awoodland You are right routing tables,`ip route` helps. `ifconfig` shows metric=1 for all. But we still have internal situations where we need to use eth5 selectively.

Comment: @Humble Debugger So the destination is accessible through many interfaces and you want to use a specific one as source ?

Comment: @Humble Debugger what is the default route for the IP?  Also, how is your HFT doing?

Comment: @Humble Debugger - did you try my answer below? If so, did it not help?

Answer (score 8):

According to the information [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/setsockoptman.html) you can use `setsockopt()` to achieve this as follows:

```
char* interface = "eth5";
setsockopt( socket_file_descriptor_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface, 4 );
```

The final parameter, 4, represents the number of bytes in the interface variable.

Comment: Should probably use sizeof(interface) instead of 4 for that last argument.

Comment: @Avner You are wrong. interface contain an address to the string literal "eth5". It in not an array itself. It is a pointer to an array. So, its size will be sizeof(char *) which is the pointer size on that machine. As far as I know, we have three option here: 1. make interface a char array. and pass the sizeof(interface). 2. Using constant 4 is Ok, But magic numbers are not welcome most of the time. strlen(interface) is an another option. 3. Use the macro IFNAMSIZ.