# How to send data by a given device (which is not a default device)?

Tags: linux, sockets, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a C++ TCP client socket on a specific network interface Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057482/using-a-c-tcp-client-socket-on-a-specific-network-interface-linux-unix)

I want to write a socket program on Ubuntu, and there are many network devices in my PC.
The program will send a UDP packet to ServerA by DeviceA, 
but in routing table, default device to the ServerA is DeviceB, 
how do I send the packet by DevideA without modify the routing table?

Thanks a lot!

/* I use C or C++ */

/* Note: DeviceA is a wireless interface, e.g: "wlan0". */

/* Note: I found a way on internet --> libnet, but it's not support the wireless interface. */

Comment: Are you *commenting* your own question? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to use the `SO_BINDTODEVICE` option with [`setsockopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt). The code is something like this (untested):

```
const char *interface = "wlan0";

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface, strlen(interface));
```